# VB6 Memory Limitations

Tags: memory, vb6

I'm currently supporting a VB6 application (that we are replacing, but it's a slow process!) that is running on several servers. Can anyone tell me please what the maximum amount of memory of VB6 process can address is? We are using a variety of operating systems:

- Windows Server 2003 32bit
- Windows Server 2008 64bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit

I've tried using resources like this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/04/10/chat-question-memory-limits-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-processes/

But I'm skeptical if this is accurate due to it discussing .NET based applications, however I can't find anything more on point than this.

Comment: [Visual Basic Specifications, Limitations, and File Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733725(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix: Although your link is great (thanks for it) I did not found there the answer of 2GB for a 32 bit process. And this 2 GB limit (never tested the 3GB switch) exists for 32 bit applications (VB6 is 32 bit), even if the os can adress more (as you know from 64bit os)

Comment: Interesting question. Why not just write a function to confirm it?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat  I don't even have a VB6 IDE. This is not an app we have source code for. I'm firefighting by managing the inputs into the app.

Comment: @Paul Sorry did not get that from your description.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to take these "What if Superman got in a fight with God" questions too seriously.  Long before this becomes a concern you should have moved from memory-resident data structures to a disk file or a database anyway.

But even without linking with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE and booting into 3GB mode a VB6 program can address quite a bit of data on 32-bit Windows.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Main()
    Const MAX_BYTES As Long = &H63700000
    Dim Bytes() As Byte

    ReDim Bytes(MAX_BYTES)
    Bytes(MAX_BYTES) = 255
    MsgBox "Success" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
         & "Bytes(MAX_BYTES) = " & CStr(Bytes(MAX_BYTES)) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
         & "MAX_BYTES = " & Format$(MAX_BYTES, "#,##0")
End Sub
```

Result:

```
Success

Bytes(MAX_BYTES) = 255

MAX_BYTES = 1,668,284,416
```

The linked blog post is correct in pointing out the limitations of a .Net process and their inability to cope with using large amounts of data.  Scripting engines like .Net just are not built for these things, and don't underestimate the overhead of the gigantic libraries even the simplest .Net program drags into its address space.

Comment: I suspect the app doesn't free up memory properly. This is not a hypothetical but an actual issue that I'm firefighting with an app with a defunct vendor.