# ReDim Byte array - "Out of memory" error?

Tags: vb6

When I try to initialize(ReDim) Byte array with long data type then I am getting Run-time error : Out of memory exception.

I have tried many ways but still no luck. It is Throwing Out of memory error if I ReDim Byte > 200000000

```
Dim bArr() As Byte
Dim lSize As Long
lSize = 210000000
ReDim bArr(0 To lSize)   'This statement is throwing out of memory error
```

I want the Byte Array to accept the range of Long variable but getting Out of Memory error

Comment: Edited as per ur suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: So It requests 210,000,000 bytes of RAM, approx 200 MB.  This other post suggests that a limit over 1GB should be possible on a 32 bit computer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771621/3195477  Not clear to me what limit your hitting.

Comment: On my computer, I don't experience this error until around 400,000,000 bytes.  I'm also not clear what is happening.

Comment: I am using 64 bit computer. Is it really depend on RAM?

Comment: VB6 is 32 bit so it could conceivably the the limit of a 32 bit process.

Comment: He actually needs 210MB of contiguous memory address space. This would normally be available unless his program uses a lot of memory. `Dim x(210000000) As Byte` is sufficient.

Comment: But my problem is that I am not able to upload a document more than 300MB, if I try it is throwing out of memory error. Is there any possibility to overcome this?

Comment: You try to "upload" ... please explain what you try to do with your byte array. Maybe there is an alternative to handling the complete file at once.

Comment: The byte array contains the binary stream of input file. What is that alternative?