# How to fix Run Time Error '7' Out of memory in visual basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I am trying to ZIP a folder with sub folders and files in vb6. For that I read each file and store them one by one in byte array using Redim Preserve. But large folders having size larger than 130MB throw an Out of Memory error.I have 8 GB of RAM in my PC so it shouldn't be a problem.So, is this some limitation by visual basic 6 that we can't use more than 150MB memory?

```
'Length of a particular File is determined
lngFileLen = FileLen(a_strFilePath)

DoEvents
If lngFileLen <> 0 Then
    m_lngPtr = m_lngPtr + lngFileLen

    'Next line Throws error once m_lngPtr reaches around 150 MB
    ReDim Preserve arrFileBuffer(1 To m_lngPtr)
```

Comment: VB6 limits arrays independently of PC memory size. (I don't know exact limits.) You likely need to use smaller buffers or just use (free) 3rd party zip libraries.

Comment: Here is a recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56059268/5162073) on the same topic.  See if it helps.

Comment: Surely there is a more efficient way to create a ZIP file than reading in their contents yourself? Use a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, VB6 arrays can only be resized to a maximum of 2,147,483,647 elements.  However, since that's also the upper limit of a `Long` in VB6, it seems like that's unlikely to be the problem.  However, even though it may be allowed to make an array that big, it's running in a 32-bit process, so it's still subject to the limit of 2GB of addressable memory for the whole process.  Since the VB6 run-time has some overhead, it's using some of that memory for other things, and since your program is likely doing other things too, that will be using up some memory too.

In addition to that, when you create an array, the system has to find that number of bytes of *contiguous* memory.  So, even when there is enough memory available, within the 2GB limit, if it's sufficiently fragmented, you can still get out of memory errors.  For that reason, creating gigantic arrays is always a concern.

Next, you are using `ReDim Preserve`, which requires twice the memory.  When you resize the array like that, what it actually has to do, under the hood, is create a second array of the new size and then copy all of the other data out of the old array into the new one.  Once it's done copying all the data out of the source array, it can then delete it, but while it's performing the copy, it needs to hold both the old array and the new array in memory simultaneously.  That means that in a best case scenario, even if there was no other allocated memory or fragmentation, the maximum memory size of an array that you could resize would be 1GB.

Finally, in your example, you never showed what the data type of the array was.  If it's an array of bytes, you should be good, I think (where the memory size of the array would only be slightly more than it's length in elements).  However, if, for instance, it's an array of strings or variants, then I believe that's going to require a minimum of 4 bytes per element, thereby more-than-quadrupling the memory size of the array.

Comment: It is indeed a byte array. But still it goes out of memory around 150MB. Doesn't array allocation always require contiguous memory allocation in all languages? I am pretty sure that I can allocate more than 150MB of memory in JAVA/C#, so why such pro blem in vb6?

Comment: @ShobhinGoyal I don't know.  The only other thing I could think of has to do with when the memory get's freed.  VB6 uses reference counting for it's automatic memory management, so my assumption would be that once the resizing of the array is complete, the runtime would immediately free the memory from the previous copy of the data.  However, I don't know for a fact that it does do that immediately.  There is a slight possibility that, for some reason, the runtime defers that operation until later and the old one stays in memory for some period of time after calling `.ReDim`

Comment: I did a quick search and couldn't find an obvious answer on that.  I'm no expert on the VB6 runtime, so I certainly can't answer that off the top of my head.